# Objective C - difference between init and constructor?

Tags: objective-c, constructor, init

I'm trying to find the difference between init and constructor in Objective C.I'm not a C developer, but I need to convert some Objective C-code to Java and actually I can't understand the difference between both things.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In Objective-C, the way an object comes to life is split into two parts: *allocation* and *initialization*.

You first allocate memory for your object, which gets filled with zeros (except for some Objective-C internal stuff about which you don't need to care):

```
myUninitializedObjectPointer = [MyClass alloc];
```

The next stage is initialization. This is done through a method that starts with `init` by convention. You should stick to this convention for various reasons (especially when using ARC), but from a language point of view there's no need to.

```
myObjectPointer = [myUnitializedObjectPointer init];
```

or in one line:

```
myObjectPointer = [[MyClass alloc] init];
```

In other languages these `init` methods are called *constructors*, but in Objective-C it is not enforced that the "constructor" is called when the object is allocated. It's your duty to call the appropriate `init` method. In languages like C++, C# and Java the allocation and initialization are so tightly coupled that you cannot allocate an object without also initializing it.

So in short: the `init` methods can be considered to be constructors, but only by naming convention and not language enforcement. To Objective-C, they're just normal methods.

Comment: +1 The *allocation* step also sets the `isa` instance variable so that it points to the object’s class.